# Getting error - "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" when I try to run flutter app on iPhone SE

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to run a skeleton app that compiles and works fine on the simulator, but doesn't run on the actual iPhone SE device.
Getting error -**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**
Mac - 10.15.5,
iPhone SE 20 (13.6.1),
Flutter - 1.17.5

I tried all suggestions I could find - cleaning derived data, pods clean/ install, restart mac, everything. But couldn't figure out whats the problem.
I recently got a developer account too. But still this error.

```
App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/
App.framework/flutter_assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/
App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/
App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/
App.framework/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf

sent 31997420 bytes  received 276 bytes  63995392.00 bytes/sec
total size is 31992548  speedup is 1.00
building file list ... done
Flutter.framework/
Flutter.framework/Flutter
Flutter.framework/Info.plist
Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/
Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

sent 98452082 bytes  received 120 bytes  39380880.80 bytes/sec
total size is 98439669  speedup is 1.00
/Users/smita/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner- 
beowdflneetuphdplieauikvuyjp/Build/Products/Debug- 
iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**
```

Comment: Have you tried run `flutter clean` and then trying to build again?

Comment: it did not help